# Is it possible to web scape the pythagorean win/loss record column using beautiful soup and save data to excel?

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

This is my first scrape. I have tried watching some videos online and using google. I haven't had much success with this website, though. Perhaps someone can help me.

This is what I have started with...

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 

req = requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB- 
standings.shtml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml") 

W_L = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'record_pythag'})]

team = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'team_ID'})]

my_dict = dict(zip(team, W_L))

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my1st_webscrape.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

I would just like the pythagorean win/loss column please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for all `td` tags that include `data-stat` corresponding to `record_pythag` and extract `.text` from each:

```
W_L = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'record_pythag'})]
```

Note that this assumes all tags found will include text. If one does not it will throw a `NoneType` error, in which case you could wrap this in a `try-except` block.

I imagine the dictionary you want to create uses the team name abbreviations as the keys, in which case you can assemble a list of them like so:

```
team = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'team_ID'})]
```

Then you can create your dictionary:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(team, W_L))
```

And pass it to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

**EDIT**

It turns out you actually need Selenium in order to pull the information you are interested in. Selenium allows you to automate a web browser and it will load the full page source HTML. You will also need to convert the dictionary to a pandas Series prior to passing it to the DataFrame constructor. See revised code below (note that you will need to download the selenium chrome driver, or whichever web browser driver you are interested in using):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

os.chdir('path your chrome driver')
header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB-standings.shtml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()

W_L = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'record_pythag'})]

team = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'team_ID'})]

my_dict = dict(zip(team, W_L))

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(my_dict))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my1st_webscrape.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rahlf23! I ran the updated code and it created an excel spreadsheet. The excel sheet is empty, though. Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you called `writer.save()`?

Comment: Yes sir... I copied and pasted all of the above code. I see the new excel file get created each time... I just don't see any info in the sheet.

Comment: Have you tried running the code by chance? I am just curious if it is working for you. I am likely doing something wrong. Not exactly sure what you mean by the dataframe being empty... This is what I have for that line:   df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

Comment: Your edit worked to perfection @rahlf23! I am very grateful for you taking the time to help me out. Thank you sir!